# How do I load HTML from a string and have AngularJS bindings work

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angular project that will be loading external HTML from a string variable into a div that currently has a controller scoped to it.

The HTML that I will be loading from the var will have angular bindings in the html. Once loaded the bindings don't seem to work. I'm wondering how I get angular to recognize the new HTML and parse the bindings so that content renders properly.

Right now the HTML loads but I end up seeing things like {{myvar}} render as text and not render the scoped variables.

Comment: Could you post your code please? Check your browser console as well. If something like the controller fails to bind properly, you'll see an error in the console and this sort of behavior in your output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do manually what angular does automatically inside ng-view directive.
Something like along those lines should do the trick:

```
var html = '...';
var linker = $compile(html); // compile html
var element = linker($scope, function () { // remember to pass correct scope here
}); // link compiled html with scope
$('.target-div').append(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Output to your element like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="myvar.name"></p>
```